# Record isn't displayed in MySQL but I can get it by ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a weird situation with my MySQL database and PHP.

When I try to get all records in MySQL I get result like this:

```
mysql> select * from adresatai;
+----+-------------+------------------+--------------+-------------------------

    -----------+
    | ID | name      | surname          | mobile    | email                              |
    +----+-------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------------+
    |  6 | ex1    | ex2           | 123456789 | email@email.com     |
    |  7 | ex3  | ex4   | 987654321 | email@emailo.com     ||
    |  9 | ex5      | ex6        | +123456 | email@emaillll.com |
 +----+-------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------------+
```

As you see record with 8 ID is missing, and at the of 7 record there is a double | (||).

But when I try to retrieve by id I get something like this:

```
mysql> select * from adresatai WHERE ID=8;
+----+--------+------------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
| ID | name | surname          | mobile    | email                          |
+----+--------+-----------ius   | 123456789 | good@email.com |+
+----+--------+------------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I don't use UTF8 characters in the website where I updated record from it's fine, but when I try to add as example Š it becomes like this. But I have few more entries that has Ž in it, but they're good.

Table is set to utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was with charset that I set in PHP while connecting to database. So the solution was to add

```
mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

in function where I connect to database.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Well it's the same thing. Either you do it before you open your console or you do it from 'my.cnf' (if you don't want to type it every time as I mentioned above) or of course you set it in php. The main thing is that you enforce utf8 on your connection.

Answer (score 2):

Try to start your client with this option `--default-character-set=utf8`.

You can check more about this here:
[10.1.4 Connection Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html)

You can also change this behavior in `[mysqld]` section in `my.cnf` and add two strings:

```
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
```

You can also add

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

to enforce using of utf8 encoding in db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you client is in UTF8 too, otherwise you can get this type of weird display glitch.

To change the charset during a connection, execute `SET NAMES utf8;`